# How to drag a View Controller on top of a View Controller?

Tags: xcode, view, uiviewcontroller, drag

I have a View Controller that is presented when you first open the app, and I have another controller that can be shown on screen if you tap a button at the top of the screen. However, instead of doing it this way I was wondering if I can either drag the view down or tap the button and have an animation take care of that.

I have tried doing this with a PageView Controller, but this doesn't show the effect I wanted as it simply translates over to the next view and doesn't actually keep the initial view fixed in place while the second view slides over it.

Also, instead of a view controller would a view initially placed out of bounds in the main View Controller work? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a side menu like MMDrawerController that has 4 type of animations for presenting the viewController.

Or you can create your custom UIView (not viewController) even using Interface Builder and animate that screen yourself. The animation can be started using **UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer**.